# Validation google form

Tags: google-forms

I have a form where you can write a question.
The worry that I have, is that when I choose to write another question, it erases the previous question.

Is it possible to validate the previous question before you can write another one?

Thanks in advance.

Cordially.

[My file.](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Ib8uyooFCnJD2Naj_s5NF2E_x2F4YAvdIHppRchSWaY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Don't make us read a linked file. Include a [mcve] *in* your question. If you have questions, visit [ask].

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy i don't understand :( i want validate an answer when i choose "yes" for write a new answer.

Comment: Having followed your link, I see that your question is about Google Forms, not programming. That makes it a bad fit for this site. You'd get better traction from [webapps.se].

Comment: Thanks @AryaMcCarthy for you help.